# "A sight ahead stopped ..."

Tags: phrase-usage

Is this a common phrase? I thought it was but then I consulted Google and only got [3](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&q=%22a%20sight%20ahead%20%20stopped%20%20%22&oq=%22a%20sight%20ahead%20%20stopped%20%20%22&gs_l=serp.3...40466.40466.0.40605.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.0.0.8NYgKPcBli8) results.

Maybe there's something wrong with the phase or a more common version?

Example:

> I ran into the crop field. Before I could go far, though, a sight
>   ahead stopped me.

Comment: Why would it not be ?

Comment: It's very easily interpreted by a native English speaker.  A "sight" (something seen) ahead caused the individual to stop.  Eg, the sight of a dead body might cause one to stop.

Comment: I think it would be better with *the*.  But it would be even better reworded: e.g. "I ran in amongst the crops [in the field] but the sight before me stopped me dead in my tracks."

Answer (score -1):

No, that is a weird expression.  As a standalone phrase, I was unable to guess what it could mean.  However, it makes more sense in context.

Some ideas for alternate wordings:

> I ran into the field.  Before I could go far, seeing the spectacle ahead transfixed me.
>
> I ran into the field but before I could go far, the <*whatever it was* (UFO, Princess, etc.)> made me stop.